# Проблема открытия web-страницы на Android через WebView

Tags: android, activity

Всем привет. Изучаю Android, создал Activity. На нем разместил Web view. Нажимаю кнопку в одном Activity, открывается Webview и открывается страница, которую я передаю, все нормально. Передаю вот так.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru/"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Но если я передаю строку больше, например:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru/yandsearch?text=ipod"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Открывается свой стандартный браузер. Мое Activity не открывается.

Что делать?

Answer (score 2):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте после первой строки
`intent.setClass(текущийКласс.this, активитиБраузера.class);`